# File Manager ( resource container )

Tags: c++, resources, file-management

I started making something like resource class where I can keep all my files like images and sounds for my application, but it got really messy and everything is being loaded in the beggining of the applications.

This is the class that contains everything:
https://sourceb.in/S8rJGQQgss ( header file )
https://sourceb.in/cjiq78HdOV ( part of the cpp file )

I'm sorry for posting it in different website, but as you can see it is really messy and I have no idea how I can make it better.

Could you please give me an example or guide me to somewhere ?

Comment: If you want a code review there’s a site for that, but do read their help section first to understand how they operate. This site is for specific programming problems, as you can see from the [help] and from taking the [tour]

Comment: I would say it is more like a problem because I want to understand how to make something like File Manager which regulates my files, but I have no idea how to make such a thing.

Comment: That may be a problem, but it’s not specific enough. It’s a very broad one so it doesn’t fit well here since it’s not helpful to others. If you have a more specific issue then that may fit here

Comment: You might consider a more generic container and provide it with a configuration file that lists all the resources for each program that uses it. Maybe give each resource a name so that your program can find it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest at least following:

1. Separate textures, sizes and audio into different files
2. The functions seems to have common naming scheme, i.e. one.png and onePlace.png. Maybe you could create a function that adds the "Place" part so that every two lines become just one line.
3. Also instead of writing one.png, two.png, three.png, ... etc, you could write  1.png, 2.png, 3.png ... and then you could use a for loop to load the files.

Comment: What if I wanted to not load all of them at the beggining ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what kind of behavior you are expecting, but you could use thread and mutex libraries to load the data on the background. You can also create some kind of event handlers that load the data based on user action or timer value.